# How can I create an array of deques?

Tags: c++, arrays, deque

I have a lot of deques defined, and when I need to do things like erase or pop all of them, I've just had to do it to every deque specifically.
What i thought could make it easier was to  put the deques in an array or list of some kind, which I could loop through.

What I want to do is something like this (Basicly just pseudocode):

```
deque<f32> pos, vel, rot, prop;
deque deques[] = {pos, vel, rot, prop};
for(i=0; i<deques.length; i++) deques[i].pop_back();
```

(But it doesn't work)

Comment: arrays don't have a `length` parameter (this is not Java), you need to explicitly know the length or somehow calculate it. The type also has to match, `deque<f32> deques[] = {..};` - use `vector` as answered by Andrew though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you declare a simple unmanaged array:

```
deque deques[] = {pos, vel, rot, prop};
```

...but you forget to declare the full specialised type of its contents, which should be `deque<f32>` not just a naked `deque`.

Now, you try to iterate over your array,

```
for(i=0; i<deques.length; i++) deques[i].pop_back();
```

...but simple C-style arrays don't have methods like `length`. You seem to be trying to write C#, not C++!

Try this:

```
std::array<std::deque<float>, 4> deques = { pos, vel, rot, prop };
for(auto i=0; i<deques.size(); i++) deques[i].push_back(1.0f);
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your comiler supports C++11 features, an alternative to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::deque<f32>, 4> deques;

std::for_each(deques.begin(),
              deques.end(),
              [](const std::deque<f32>& a_d)
              {
                  std::cout << a_d.size() << "\n";
              });
```

If not, you can use `std::vector` as already stated. To create the `std::vector` with initial `deque<f32>` elements:

```
std::vector<std::deque<f32> > deques(4); // 4 empty deque<f32>s

for (std::vector<std::deque<f32> >::iterator i = deques.begin();
     i != deques.end();
     i++)
{
      std::cout << i->size() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::deque<f32>> array;

std::deque pos, vel, rot, prop;

array.push_back(pos);
array.push_back(vel);
array.push_back(rot);
array.push_back(prop);
```